# Google Apps Script - Insert image in a Google Slides Table

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-slides-api

There are many ways to insert images to a table cell in Google Docs/Sheets, but how about Google Slides?

I used Google Apps Script and found that `appendImage` function is not in `TableCell` object: [Class TableCell of google apps scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-cell)

```
var NAME = "Test slide 2018/7/3";
var deck = SlidesApp.create(NAME);

function addImageSlide(link,index) {
  var slide = deck.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK);
//  var image = slide.insertImage(link);
  var table = slide.insertTable(3, 4)
  var cell = table.getCell(0,0)
  cell.appendImage(link);
}

function main(){
  var images = [
    "https://thehousenewsbloggers.files.wordpress.com/2016/12/440_4079.jpg",
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRMKzX5vtY5jMcBI3OQgv6LUNbd5uJZXiVhSozd_cyg9Fl2tPWC",
  ];
  var [title, subtitle] = deck.getSlides()[0].getPageElements();
  title.asShape().getText().setText(NAME);
  subtitle.asShape().getText().setText("Google Apps Script\nSlides Service demo")
  images.forEach(addImageSlide);
}
```

And I used Google Slides API, I can't create an image inside the table cell.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Show your code, or any work

Comment: I didn't think you could add an image into a table cell outside the `api`. Is there functionality that is available via the `api` not available in the app?

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I can do it in Docs first then paste to the Slides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

You cannot insert image to table cell via Slides API.

### Explanation

From https://developers.google.com/slides/api/guides/add-image:

> Images in the Slides API **are a type of page element**. As with any page element, you specify the visual size and position of the image using the size and transform properties of the PageElement.

So image can be inserted as a direct child of a slide only.

Comment: I thought this function could both be done via Slides or Docs API before. I'm misunderstanding. Thanks for answer.